# Serial port logging

Tags: windows, logs

I need a Windows program to log serial port activity.  I'll have data arriving in spurts of maybe 1,000 characters, four times per second.  This will be going on for roughly 24 hours.  I'd love time stamps entered into the data stream, but I can live without that.

I need reliable logging without user intervention.  By reliable, I mean that the file should be as bulletproof as I can get it.  If somebody pulls the plug, the file should be intact.  Saves should happen periodically, if not constantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Aggsoft advanced serial data logger](http://www.aggsoft.com/serial-data-logger.htm):

- non-free
- Windows
- many features (filtering/logging/etc.) as the two other free solutions but also can pipe into some RDMS and has a few more features.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Portmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx):

- free
- Windows
- Sysinternals quality
- monitors and displays all serial and parallel port activity on a system
- filtering and search capabilities

[image]

Comment: Portmon is good, but unfortunately there are times when it does not detect any COM ports on Windows XP.

Comment: FYI: Portmon does [not work on x64](http://forum.sysinternals.com/portmon-for-64-bit_topic26245.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Eltima RS232 Data Logger](http://www.eltima.com/products/rs232-data-logger/):

- free
- Windows
- logs data from any serial port (virtual or real one)

[image]

Comment: Not 'Free' at all. Free 14 day demo then $70 Std / $150 pro. I was hoping to use it instead of the Serial monitor in the Arduino IDE, for 2 port devices like LInkitOne, but niether Eltima nor Putty worked, so back to the IDE.

Answer (score 3):

In case you are interested, the Serial Console Logging with the Text Highlights with Timestamps, as well as get a HTML report Generated ? Check out this Free & powerful Console Application.
https://hiterminallogger.sourceforge.io/

(you need windows Console emulators like git Bash for example.)
[image]

[image]